# get data from tables using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I need help in creating stored procedure. i am working on school system and i want to get fee detail from different table. First of all please see the code i have written

```
@payment_id varchar(150), @campus_id varchar(150) as
begin
  select  s.GR,s.Name,s.FatherName,c.Class+' (' +s.Section+ ')' as Class,f.ChallanNo,f.IssueDate,f.DueDate,f.FeeMonth,t.Name as FeeName,
d.Amount 
  from FeePayment f 
  join Student s ON s.StudentId = f.FkStudentId
                and f.PaymentId = @payment_id
                and f.FkCampusId = @campus_id
  join ClassDetail c ON c.ClassId = s.FkClassId
  join FeeDetail d ON f.PaymentId = d.FkpaymentId       
  join FeeType t  ON t.TypeId = d.FkFeeTypeId
end
```

this code is working fine but in FeeType i want to add a scenario when t.TypeId !=d.FkFeeTypeId then the d.FkFeeTypeId return. i am having a fee type table in which all the feetypes are mentioned and in generating fee i added extra textbox of feetype for a case if feetype is not mentioned in feetype table so the user can manually write feetype and amount. while getting fee detail all the feetypes which are found in feetype table are selected and if feetype are not found in its table then the d.FkFeeTypeId are select as it is. 
sorry for my bad english :) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When t.TypeId !=d.FkFeeTypeId, you are expecting to get a new row in the result? or you would like to have a column for each FeeType in your result?

Comment: Pretty sure all you need is to change the join on FeeType to be a left join. And do yourself a favor, don't be scared of using some white space. When you cram everything left aligned and leave no spaces your queries are a LOT harder to read than they need to be.

Comment: @SeanLange - he had lotsa crazy tabs in there.

Comment: make every join a left join and see what happens!

Comment: @Hogan does three left joins make a right join? LOL.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't know how much it will cost Moeed, but if there is no fee he should try and see.

Comment: Thanks alot guys all of your i am trying as you said and will reply you if its work. I know its more complicated query as it be because it is not written by me :) i am just using it in my code.

Comment: Feryal Badili when t.Type!=d.FkFeeTypeid i am expecting a new row in the result but the text in this cell of Typeid =d.FkTypeId as it is. in other word i am saying that if d.fkfeetypeid is found in t.type id then join should work otherwise join should not work and the value in d.fktypeid return as it is.
hope you'll understand

Answer (score 0):

As a recommendation, in join queries don´t use negative operators. If you need to use negative operators use it on the where part.